# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: No database selected: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, console, rds

I have an app deployed to AWS EC2 and using AWS RDS service. The app is working but when I try to use rails console production and look up the User table I get the following error: Any ideas on how I can fix this?

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: No database selected: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'users'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `query'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `block in execute'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:245:in `execute'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:259:in `execute_and_free'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:383:in `tables'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:390:in `table_exists?'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:30:in `table_exists?'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:223:in `table_exists?'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:423:in `inspect'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

This is my database.yml

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

From the terminal I'm using these commands:

```
% bundle exec rails console production
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.13)
1.9.3-p374 :001 > User.all
```

Comment: Can you show us the codes you run?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, didn't find a solution as far as I can remember.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of those env variables are blank. Try running each in the console on its own.

Comment: They're all nil when I check them in the rails console. I deployed following the AWS Elastic Beanstalk docs, I've tried substituting in the values from the RDS Management console, but it still isn't working. The error says it can't connect to host xxxx.yyy.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com